# STM32 Nucleo board, SD card displaying symbols instead of numbers

Tags: stm32, c, sd, code

Devices: STM32F4

The SD is working and the data is saving on the SD, but the problem is that the integers are displayed as symbols in this SD. So I think that the problem is that the function I used needs `char`, and the data is `int`, so is there any way to convert `int` into `char` for 2 digits?

Code:

```
while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc,&sTime,RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
        HAL_RTC_GetDate(&hrtc, &sDate, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);

char month = sDate.Month;

        /* Mount SD Card */
  if(f_mount(&fs, "", 0) != FR_OK)
Error_Handler();  
  /* Open file to write */
  if(f_open(&fil, "second.txt", FA_OPEN_ALWAYS | FA_READ | FA_WRITE) != FR_OK)
Error_Handler();  
  /* Check free space */
  if(f_getfree("", &fre_clust, &pfs) != FR_OK)
Error_Handler();  
  total = (uint32_t)((pfs->n_fatent - 2) * pfs->csize * 0.5);
  free1 = (uint32_t)(fre_clust * pfs->csize * 0.5);   

  /* Free space is less than 1kb */
  if(free1 < 1)
Error_Handler();  
  /* Writing text */
    if(freq <=120000 && freq>= 80000){
          f_puts(&month, &fil);  
  f_puts("\n", &fil);  


    }
  /* Close file */
  if(f_close(&fil) != FR_OK)
Error_Handler();  
  /* Open file to read */
  if(f_open(&fil, "second.txt", FA_READ) != FR_OK)
Error_Handler();  
  while(f_gets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &fil))
  {
    //printf("%s", buffer);
  }

  /* Close file */
  if(f_close(&fil) != FR_OK)
Error_Handler();  
  /* Unmount SDCARD */
  if(f_mount(NULL, "", 1) != FR_OK)
Error_Handler();  

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the variable data directly to the file. You need to convert the data into a printable text string of ascii symbols and write the string to the file. You can use sprintf to do it, almost like when printing to serial port with printf.